# Reading text files with different numbers of integers into multiple lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, file-io

I have a file that looks like this

```
 25,6,73,5,3
 3,4,5
 0,6,3,78
 53,68,9,3
```

how can it be read as integers and put into a list of lists( per row), without a fixed list size and number of lists?(meaning i can put as many numbers into one row and as many rows as i want)

Comment: Please read a Python tutorial - this is a very basic question and is explained in almost every Python tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file, read line by line by iterating the open file object; split the line using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), convert splited strings to [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

```
>>> with open('/path/to/textfile.txt') as f:
...     numbers = [map(int, line.strip().split(',')) for line in f]
...
>>> numbers
[[25, 6, 73, 5, 3], [3, 4, 5], [0, 6, 3, 78], [53, 68, 9, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick (not tested):

```
with open(fileName) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
listOfLists = []
for line in content:
    listOfLists.append(line.split(','))
```